# can not find default viewport shading lights in blender installation , program files folders in windows

Tags: lighting, hdri

to add default lights textures in world as environment texture and make the texture visible in final render image , watched some videos to get the texture . According to videos default light textures of viewport shading modes are located in either program files folders or blender installation folders . My both folders are missing lights textures , there is no folder of blender any of the version containing textures . I tried viewport shading render but results were not required , is there an other way to make lights textures visible in final render ? or to find the default lighting textures ?

[image]

This is viewport shading light texture view .

[image]

This is the render image .

Answer (score 2):

The viewport HDRIs are located in (x.x being the version of Blender you're using)

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender x.x\x.x\datafiles\studiolights\world

If you intend to use them often, I recommend copying them to a common folder that you place your normal HDRIs in.

Comment: it is not there

Comment: can anyone suggest anything ?

Comment: What did you encounter when inspecting that path? Depending on your Blender version and install directory you might have to navigate somewhere else, but the relative location of the .exr files in the "datafiles" directory should be correct.